# Class 'int' has no instance getter 'id' with filter list data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to make filter list data in flutter to filter the id or name from api data but I get every time this error:

```
Class 'int' has no instance getter 'id'.
Receiver: 1171
Tried calling: id
```

My page code:

```
class testpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const testpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _testpageState createState() => _testpageState();
}

class _testpageState extends State<testpage> {
  var apiURL;
  @override
  void initState() {
    Searchgetdata();
    super.initState();
  }

  List listsearch = [];
  Future Searchgetdata() async {
    apiURL =
    '**************';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiURL));
    setState(() {
      List jsonList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonList.length; i++) {
       listsearch.add(jsonList[i]['id']);
print(listsearch);
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _filteredList = listsearch.where((product) => product.id == '1202').toList();//here problem......
   print(_filteredList);
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
          children: [

    ]
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm sure the api connection is correct and the data is fetched through it.

Update this is print data what I get from api:
I make this line like that to just print id:

```
   listsearch.add(jsonList[i]['id']);
```

then I get this data:

```
I/flutter ( 4792): [695, 523, 908, 522, 987, 727, 1162, 1586, 862, 746, 780, 916, 1428, 1218, 686, 745, 942, 902, 829, 851, 751, 792, 713, 900, 910, 532, 698, 913, 690, 668, 836, 663, 1221, 849, 928, 679, 898, 852, 909, 1229, 1223, 824, 742, 875, 1169, 1407, 1029, 901, 611, 893, 1203, 1202, 1340, 688, 681, 1215, 1170, 922, 895, 1036, 724, 1211, 1249, 737, 1224, 872, 1220, 1168, 796, 662, 682, 822, 670, 680, 669, 1409, 789, 856, 912, 689, 517, 1410, 897, 605, 921, 1138, 612, 1163, 1263, 741, 1226, 1219, 904, 783, 1228, 725, 1213, 864, 795, 1204, 903, 1276, 613, 1206, 1433, 965, 1216, 696, 527, 714, 1230, 981, 736, 894, 610, 672, 609, 854, 790, 691, 914, 855, 966, 896, 666, 723, 831, 797, 687, 722, 726, 674, 1201, 850, 1171, 738, 739, 1099, 899, 848, 671, 684, 964, 743, 1255, 787, 1172, 694, 1118, 1227, 750, 870, 566, 525, 915, 1100, 917, 1342, 1205, 1408, 667, 606, 794, 665, 1113, 608, 847, 536, 853, 685, 1160, 607, 675, 699, 516, 906, 1225, 1212, 865, 866, 863, 740, 701, 673, 907, 728, 1431, 911, 1222, 1256, 712, 683, 748, 121
```

anyone can help me
thanks you

Comment: is `id ` a `string` or an `integer `

Comment: Hi bro .. its integer  but I try also with string like name and I get same error @Denzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `listsearch` is a list of ids, not of products.

```
listsearch.add(jsonList[i]['id']);
```

You add the id of the item to the jsonList, not the id itself, but here

```
final _filteredList = listsearch.where((product) => product.id == '1202').toList();//here problem......
```

You try to access the `.id` again. An id (integer) does not have an `.id` attribute!

If you want to add every object to your list, then search for a specific id you should do

```
listsearch.add(jsonList[i]);
```

And then you can search for the object with an `['id']` attribute equal to 1202.

Comment: Hi bro / I make first line like that : listsearch.add(jsonList[i]); in  Future Searchgetdata() and then I make second line like that:   final _filteredList = listsearch.where((jsonList) => jsonList.id == '738').toList(); but still I get error : Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'id'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:119
Tried calling: id

Comment: @MAl try `['id']` instead of `.id`. Should look like `final _filteredList = listsearch.where((jsonList) => jsonList['id'] == '738').toList();`

Comment: Hi bro / I make it like that :   final _filteredList = listsearch.where((jsonList) => jsonList['id'] == '738').toList(); // but now I don't get any error but also no data nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? The print statement here `print(_filteredList);` prints out an empty list? The program hangs and does not continue? If the print statement is printing an empty list, have you confirmed that there is in fact an object with `id` equal to '738'? I need to see your full output to help you.

Comment: hi bro / I updated the question

Comment: I mean by nothing happens : I get just this : [ ]

Comment: You are comparing two different data types (integer vs string). Try this: final _filteredList = listsearch.where((jsonList) => jsonList['id'] == 695).toList(); Try a few different numbers such as 738, and 1202. Do not put them in quotes!

Comment: Hi bro / yes it's working thank you / just I want ask you if I need to changing id to name and search by just first letter to get all name how can I make that?